# Is smatch match capacity limited? Is it related to searching large strings?

Tags: c++, regex, g++

I've been using C++'s regex's to search some strings and I seem to have trouble when using large strings with not small matches.

Here is a sample I created where the problem occurs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

void FillWithHugeString(string &str);

int main() {
    smatch myMatch;
    regex myRegex(R"FancyDelim(Line 10([\s\S]*)Line 811)FancyDelim", regex::icase | regex::optimize);

    string searchMe;
    FillWithHugeString(searchMe);
    cout << "String filled, now search" << endl;

    if (regex_search(searchMe, myMatch, myRegex)) {
        cout << "Found it! ->" << myMatch[1] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void FillWithHugeString(string &str) {
    //1533 good
    //1534 bad
    const unsigned int NUM_OF_LINES = 1534;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<NUM_OF_LINES; ++i) {
        str += "Line " + to_string(i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Output when NUM_OF_LINES = 1533:

```
String filled, now search
Neat
Line 11
...
Line 810
```

Output when NUM_OF_LINES = 1534:

```
String filled, now search
Segmentation fault
```

Compiled as:

```
g++-5 -o regexCapacityTest regexCapacityTest.cpp -std=c++17

$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What could be the problem? Memory allocation issue when searching large potential substrings over a large string?

Comment: I just did a `([\S\s]+)` on 50,000 lines in a 3 meg file. Smatch plopped out the whole thing. Does `myMatch[1].c_str()` give you any better results?

Comment: `match_results` is just a container of iterator-pairs; the length is irrelevant. This works on `-O2`, but segfaults on `-O0`; my first guess is stack overflow - try `ulimit -s unlimited` and see what happens.

Comment: If the task is to find all from `Line 10` to the *closest* `Line 811`, you should think about using `Line 10\b([^L]*(?:L(?!ine 811\b)[^L]*)*)\bLine 811\b`.

Comment: @sln I see the issue even if i have a regex which doesnt have a submatch.

Comment: @T.C. I originally found the error when compiling using -O3, however I never tried -O2

Comment: @stribizhev I know there are multiple ways to find that, however I wanted to leave the regex ambiguous enough as it is in my actual program (where there are multiple matches possible)

Comment: @T.C. Just tried -O2 and still happened. However, yes, setting ulimit fixed it. Is it just the case that the regex grows too large?

Comment: @VictorStone Looks like it. GCC's `<regex>` is rather new. (Also, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61582)

Comment: I've seen that before @T.C. though for g++-5 they marked it as it was functional

Comment: @VictorStone That bug report was initially for g++-4.8 (which has no usable `<regex>` at all) but morphed into a more general "stack overflow in regex" bug.

Comment: On my system, clang-700.1.81, it works even with 153400 lines (100x more).